# 405: Method Not Allowed. Why am I getting this error in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I tried all posiible ways and read many posts in SO. I haven't got any solution for my "method not allowed" error. Can anyone check and let me know what did I do wrong? I am getting frustrated cause I am new to flask and I cannot proceed further.

This is my template file add_cars.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='navstyle.css') }}">
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="{{ url_for('root') }}">Home</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('list_ev') }}">EV List</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
    <h2>Add car details</h2>
    <div id="firebase-auth-container"></div>
    {% if user_data %}
    <p align="right">Email: {{ user_data['email'] }}</p>
    <button id="sign-out" hidden="true" style="float: right;">Sign out</button>
    <div id="login-info" hidden="true">
        <form action="/add_cars" method="post">
            Car name:<input type="text" value="" name="name_update"/><br/>
            Manufacturer:<input type="text" value="" name="manufacturer_update"/><br/>
            Year:<input type="number" value="" name="year_update"/><br/>
            Battery size:<input type="number" value="0.0" name="battery_update" step="any"/><br/>
            Range:<input type="number" value="" name="range_update"/><br/>
            Cost:<input type="number" value="" name="cost_update"/><br/>
            Power:<input type="number" value="" name="power_update" step="any"/><br/><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button-1" value="Add details" name="submit_button"/>
        </form>
        {% elif error_message %}
        <p>Error Message: {{ error_message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    <br>
<!--    <div>-->
<!--        <a href="{{ url_for('list_ev') }}" class="button-1">View all cars</a>-->
<!--    </div>-->

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app-setup.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import google.oauth2.id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests
from google.cloud import datastore
import os, random
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="google_auth_json.json"

firebase_req_adapter=requests.Request()

app = Flask(__name__)
datastore_client = datastore.Client()

def store_time(email):
    entity = datastore.Entity(key = datastore_client.key('User', email, 'visit'))
    entity.update({'email' : email})
    datastore_client.put(entity)

def retrieveCarInfo(claims):
    entity_key = datastore_client.key('CarInfo', claims['email'])
    entity = datastore_client.get(entity_key)
    return entity

def createCarInfo(claims):
    entity_key = datastore_client.key('CarInfo', claims['email'])
    entity = datastore.Entity(key = entity_key)
    entity.update({
        'email': claims['email'],
        'name': claims['name'],
        'cars_list': []
    })
    datastore_client.put(entity)

def retrieveCars(car_info):
    car_ids = car_info['cars_list']
    car_keys = []
    for i in range(len(car_ids)):
        car_keys.append(datastore_client.key('car', car_ids[i]))
    cars_list = datastore_client.get_multi(car_keys)
    return cars_list

def createCarDetails(claims, new_car_string, new_man_string, new_yr_int, new_bt_float, new_rg_int, new_cost_int, new_pr_int):
    id = random.getrandbits(63)
    entity_key = datastore_client.key('car', id)
    entity = datastore.Entity(key = entity_key)
    entity.update({
        'name': new_car_string,
        'manufacturer': new_man_string,
        'year': new_yr_int,
        'battery_size': new_bt_float,
        'range': new_rg_int,
        'cost': new_cost_int,
        'power': new_pr_int,
    })
    datastore_client.put(entity)
    return id

def addcarToUser(car_info, id):
    car_keys = car_info['cars_list']
    car_keys.append(id)
    car_info.update({
        'cars_list': car_keys
    })
    datastore_client.put(car_info)

def deleteCars(claims, id):
    car_info = retrieveCarInfo(claims)
    car_list_keys = car_info['cars_list']
    car_key = datastore_client.key('Car', car_list_keys[id])
    datastore_client.delete(car_key)
    del car_list_keys[id]
    car_info.update({
        'car_info' : car_list_keys
    })
    datastore_client.put(car_info)

# All functions below to render data to templates

@app.route("/")
def root():
    id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
    error_message = None
    claims = None
    car_info = None
    cars = None
    if id_token:
        try:
            claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(id_token,
                                                                  firebase_req_adapter)
            store_time(claims['email'])
            car_info = retrieveCarInfo(claims)
            if car_info == None:
                createCarInfo(claims)
                car_info = retrieveCarInfo(claims)
                cars = retrieveCars(car_info)
        except ValueError as exc:
            error_message = str(exc)
    return render_template('index.html', user_data=claims, error_message=error_message,
                           car_info=car_info, cars=cars)
    # return render_template('index.html', user_data=claims, error_message=error_message)

@app.route("/add_cars", methods=['POST'])
def add_ev():
    # add ev's
    id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
    error_message = None
    claims = None
    car_info = None
    if id_token and  request.method=='POST':
        try:
            claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(id_token, firebase_req_adapter)
            car_info = retrieveCarInfo(claims)
            id = createCarDetails(claims,
                                  request.form['name_update'],
                                  request.form['manufacturer_update'],
                                  request.form['year_update'],
                                  request.form['battery_update'],
                                  request.form['range_update'],
                                  request.form['cost_update'],
                                  request.form['power_update'])
            addcarToUser(car_info, id)
        except ValueError as exc:
            error_message = str(exc)

    return redirect(url_for("add_ev"))
    # return render_template('add-cars.html', user_data=claims, error_message=error_message, car_info=car_info)

@app.route("/list")
def list_ev():
    # listing all ev's
    id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
    error_message = None
    claims = None
    car_info = None
    if id_token:
        try:
            claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(id_token,
                                                                  firebase_req_adapter)
            car_info = retrieveCarInfo(claims)
            if car_info == None:
                createCarInfo(claims)
                car_info = retrieveCarInfo(claims)
        except ValueError as exc:
            error_message = str(exc)
    return render_template('list_ev.html', user_data=claims, error_message=error_message, car_info=car_info)

@app.route('/delete_cars/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def deleteCarFromUser(id):
    id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
    error_message = None
    if id_token:
        try:
            claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(id_token, firebase_req_adapter)
            deleteCars(claims, id)
        except ValueError as exc:
            error_message = str(exc)
    return redirect('/')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8082, debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? I assume when you redirect to the url for  `add_ev`, the redirect request will be a `GET` and that is not a supported method by the `add_ev` endpoint?

Comment: My intention is to add car details into the datastore from html template. The ```add_ev``` is meant to fetch the data from tempate and add it in the datastore. Isn't that supposed to a ```POST``` method?

Comment: I agree it should be a `POST` but when you redirect you will request it with `GET`, I think you should redirect to a different endpoint then, which supports `GET` and hosts the template you referenced above. Then the form of the template can `POST` to the `add_ev` endpoint, and then it redirects to the `GET` endpoint and the loop is closed.

Comment: The redirect line is intended to just refresh the page. I tried ```return redirect("/")" and the result is same. I am unsure if there's any ```GET``` involved.

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see error messages? it should show more details. Maybe it tries to use some other method: ie. `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, `DELETE`.

Comment: ```127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2022 12:49:23] "GET /add-cars HTTP/1.1" 405 -``` this is what I get in console

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You should be able to trim this down to a much smaller example that produces the same response.

Comment: Apologies, I posted the entire code as I am unsure of there's any mistake I did in any other functions or in html template. I am a beginner in flask.

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried your suggestion and I think its working. I am still trying it out. Will let you know for sure. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Szabolcs It worked. If you can add a separate comment on it, I will be able to close this question. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: @LibinThomas Updated my answer with the above suggestion! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

When you redirect you will eventually send a `GET` request to your endpoint, however your endpoint only supports `POST`.
Therefore you should make a different endpoint then, which supports `GET` and hosts the template you referenced above. Then the form of the template can send a `POST` to the `add_ev` endpoint, and then the `add_ev` redirects to the new `GET` endpoint and the loop is closed.

**Previous suggestion:**

Could you try adding `GET` as a supported method to the below endpoint?

```
@app.route("/add_cars", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_ev():
    # add ev's
    ...
```

Comment: The page just went down when I tried this. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTvpn.png]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add support for `GET` inside your `add_ev` and limit redirect to POST only (otherwise you will end with endless loop) i.e. something akin to

```
@app.route("/add_cars", methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_ev():
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for("add_ev"))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('add_cars.html')
```

Comment: I get the html page without the form part of html. Is there anything wrong in the html template?

Comment: @LibinThomas it needs to send also `user_data` to form because form is in `{% if user_data %}`

Comment: I have included that in the template @furas

Comment: @LibinThomas but now you have to run `render_template('add_cars.html' , user_data= ...)` to see it. So you have to add it in above example. And you have to check if `user_data` is not empty.